# Formatting the text in the message

Tags: alert, pine-script, message

We haven't talked for a long time.

Faced with the problem of formatting the text in the message. It is required that the message is displayed in several lines with spaces on the left.

The test sript is given below. No options give the desired result. All spaces and tabs on the left are ignored. See the screenshot.

The result that I would like to see is given in the commented lines of the script.

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © AnyDozer

//@version=5
indicator("Test message for alert")

str1 = "\{" + "\n"
str2 = "\t" + "   \"name\": \"___\"," + "\n"
str3 = "          \"secret\": \"___\","+ "\n"
str4 = "  " + "   \"side\": \"buy\"," + "\n"
str5 = "   \"symbol\": \"___\"," + "\n"
str6 = "   \"open\":  {" + "\n"
str7 = "     \"amountType\": \"___\"," + "\n"
str8 = "     \"amount\": \"___\"" + "\n"
str9 = "  }" + "\n"
str0 = "}"

if true
    alert(str1+str2+str3+str4+str5+str6+str7+str8+str9+str0, alert.freq_once_per_bar_close)

plot(0)


// {
//   "name": "___",
//   "secret": "___",
//   "side": "buy",
//   "symbol": "___",
//   "open": {
//     "amountType": "___",
//     "amount": "___"
//   }
// }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Missing spaces should not be an issue for any decent parser. I personally never think about those for my bots.

Anyways, you can try using a special character that we use to add spaces in user inputs.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script")

s = "Line 1\n Line 2\n  Line 3\n   Line 4\n    Line 5"

if (close > open)
    alert(s, alert.freq_once_per_bar_close)
    
plot(close)
```

[image]

[image]

The character is not visible on Stackoverflow but you can find it if you check the built-in MACD's source code for example.

It's the dots I marked below.
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. Are there any other special characters for formatting texts? I would be very grateful for a link to the documentation.

Comment: Those special characters are called unicode characters. You can find examples at [How can I organize my script’s inputs in the Settings/Inputs tab?](https://www.pinecoders.com/faq_and_code/#how-can-i-organize-my-scripts-inputs-in-the-settingsinputs-tab) and at [Unicode resources](https://www.pinecoders.com/resources/#unicode-resources)